# Coffeescript clear timeout with args

Tags: coffeescript, settimeout

Ive tried implementing solution 3 in this post http://evanhahn.com/smoothing-out-settimeout-in-coffeescript/ to create a delay function that I can pass arguments to. This works for me however I also need to be able to clear the timeout and I'm not sure how to do this?

```
timeout = 5000

func = (message) ->
  console.log(message)

delay = (time, fn, args...) ->
  setTimeout fn, time, args...

newEvent = {
  id: 22,
  delay: delay 5000, -> func("hi")
}
```

I would like to be able to do this or something equivalent:

```
clearTimeout(newEvent.delay)
```

I have also thought about using underscores delay function which allows passing and stopping easily however due to the max timeout length being 24 days I have to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/long-timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to clear a timeout you need to assign a variable to the timeout, and use that to clear it.

```
timeout = 5000
myTimeout = null

delay = (time, fn, args...) ->
  myTimeout = setTimeout fn, time, args...

clearTimeout(myTimeout)
```

note that you'll need to declare the timeout in a scope outside delay function

Comment: Thanks I just wasnt thinking properly

Answer (score 0):

What I finished with:

```
timeout = 5000

func = (message) ->
  console.log(message)

delay = (time, fn, args...) ->
  newEvent = {
    id: 22,
    delay: setTimeout fn, time, args...
  }

delay 5000, -> func("hi")
```